# Where does Cygwin64 store/look for Python packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin

I'm trying to use Cygwin64 to run a python script, but it's not working because for some reason it can't find the module.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "makeplot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import vplanet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vplanet'
```

Where are modules installed in Cygwin64 and How do I make sure my module is installed?

Comment: Run the following from the Cygwin command line - `/usr/bin/python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` and see what it prints out. You may need to substitute `python3` for `python`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are expecting that Cygwin version of Python should contain any type of module around.

If you look for vplanet, you will find the specific instruction for installation

https://virtualplanetarylaboratory.github.io/vplanet/install.html

```
python -m pip install vplanet
```

Have you tried it ?

Comment: Yes, I did that command before. Vplanet is installed. If I do it again it tell me it's already installed. That's why in my initial post I was asking about where Cygwin64 installs it's packages, because I think either:

A.) Vplanet is installed in the wrong directory (somehow)

B.) Cygwin64 is looking in the wrong directory for packages

Comment: with cygwin python 3.8 the command `python -m pip install vplanet` fails. Are you sure that it works on your system ?

Comment: Oh strange, the command was definitely working before. Maybe the devs of Vplanet made an update that screwed something up?